# An equality $\ast(\delta_1 \otimes \delta_2)=(-1)^{k_1k_2}(\ast_1\delta_1)\otimes(\ast_2\delta_2)$ in huybrechts's book PAGE 37

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am confused about one equatily in proposition 1.2.31 in huybrechts 's book complex geometry,
$\ast(\delta_1 \otimes \delta_2)=(-1)^{k_1k_2}(\ast_1\delta_1)\otimes(\ast_2\delta_2)$.

Can anyone give me some help?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please add more contexts (since everybody is not accessible to the book cited), at least explaining what these notations (such as $*,*_1,*_2$) mean, and the definitions of these variables (such as $\delta_i,k_i$)?

Comment: No. Although the rules are not strict, usually it is better to [be as self-contained as possible](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2675/23875), at least explaining the objects in question and the notations. If appropriate, you could also quote the proposition that you ask. See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/23875) for further suggestions. A more elementary question without contexts or efforts might attract many downvotes. When the question is more advanced, seemingly users are not that stringent, but it still benefits others to have more contexts.

Comment: That is to say, imagining a mathematician, possibly attracted by the title, looking at your question, even if he/she read Huybrechts' book before, the notations might not make enough sense without any definitions or explanations, and he/she might not bother to (re)open the book to look up the definitions to answer your question. However, if the question is more self-contained, maybe he/she will try to (re)open the book in order to answer your question. We are glad to help new users understand how to improve questions.

Comment: I have voted to close this question since it is unclear what you are asking. Please provide more context, your own thoughts and what you have tried to dissect the equation into smaller parts that you do understand. Furthermore I have flagged the comment with the link to the book on LibGen for moderator attention since we don't support piracy on this platform.

Comment: @Christoph  …fine. Someone has given the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context: Let $(V,\langle\,,\,\rangle)$ be an inner product space of dimension $n$, assume there is a decomposition $(V,\langle\,,\,\rangle)=(W_1,\langle\,,\,\rangle_1)\oplus(W_2,\langle\,,\,\rangle_2)$ and let $*_i$ be the Hodge star operators on $W_i$ respectively. The claimed statement basically follows from the fact that putting together orthonormal bases of $W_1$ and $W_2$ gives an orthonormal basis of $V$.

Let $\delta_i\in\bigwedge^{k_i}{W_i}^*$ for $k_i\leq\dim W_i$, we know $*(\delta_1\otimes\delta_2)$ is an $(n-k_1-k_2)$-form. Fix orthonormal bases $\{e_i\},\{f_j\}$ of $W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively, express $\delta_1=\sum_I a_I e_I^*$ and $\delta_2=\sum_J b_J f_J^*$ for multi-indices $I,J$ of size $k_1,k_2$ respectively. Then $\delta_1\otimes\delta_2=\sum_{I,J}a_Ib_J e^*_I\wedge f^*_J$. By reordering, we may assume $\{e_i,f_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ in the correct orientation. Then  $*(\delta_1\otimes\delta_2)=\sum_{I,J}a_Ib_J \epsilon\,e^*_{I'}\wedge f^*_{J'}$ where $I'$ is the multi-index given by all indices not in $I$, and $\epsilon=\operatorname{sgn}(I,J,I',J')$.

As for the right hand side, note that $*_1(\delta_1)=\sum_{I}a_I\epsilon_1 \,e^*_{I'}$ and $*_2(\delta_2)=\sum_{J}b_J\epsilon_2\, f^*_{J'}$, where $\epsilon_i$ is given by the sign of $(I,I')$ etc. Hence it suffices to prove that $\epsilon=(-1)^{k_1k_2}\epsilon_1\epsilon_2$ for any $I,J$. Since $\epsilon=\operatorname{sgn}(I,J,I',J')$ and $J$ and $I'$ have sizes $k_2$ and $k_1$ respectively, it takes $k_1k_2$ swaps to get it to $(I,I',J,J')$. At this point it is clear that $\operatorname{sgn}(I,I',J,J')=\operatorname{sgn}(I,I')\operatorname{sgn}(J,J')$ and the claim is proved.